# building maven flex project with flex mojo depending on apache sdk fail

Tags: apache, maven, apache-flex, flexmojos, flex-mojos

I have a mavenized flex project wich builds fine with adobe sdke 4.6.
Now , i'm trying to compile it with apache recent sdk .
I mavenized the sdk and copied the dependencies in local repo .
the apache version that i mavenized is : 4.13.0.20140701 .

my pom is as below :

```
<properties>
        <flexmojos.version>7.0.1</flexmojos.version>
        <flex.version>4.13.0.20140701</flex.version>
        <flash.version>11.1</flash.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/flex</sourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.flexmojos.oss</groupId>
                <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${flexmojos.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>

                <configuration>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <sourceFile>ComptaFlex.mxml</sourceFile>
                    <services>${basedir}/src/main/flex/services/services-config.xml</services>
                    <compilerWarnings>
                        <warn-no-constructor>false</warn-no-constructor>
                    </compilerWarnings>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- This handles a bug in maven which causes problems with flex resources -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.flexmojos.oss</groupId>
                        <artifactId>flexmojos-threadlocaltoolkit-wrapper</artifactId>
                        <version>${flexmojos.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- Without this FM will use the compiler configured in its master 
                        pom, which will result in version conflicts -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.flex</groupId>
                        <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>4.13.0.20140701</version>
                        <type>pom</type>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
```

I got maven compile error as :

```
xmojos.oss:flexmojos-flex-compiler:jar:7.0.1 -> net.flexmojos.oss:flexmojos-generator-internal-compiler-iface:jar:7.0.1 -> org.apache.flex:compiler:pom:4.12.1.20140427: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.flex:compiler:pom:4.12.1.20140427: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.
```

it seems that flex mojo always use a default apache version and ignores mine provided . how could i force flexmojo build with my given version .

Comment: In the next version I'm currently working on Flexmojos will have no dependency on any flex-artifact directly. I threw the "default-version" stuff over board in order to support the new Falcon compiler.

Comment: I would suggest you give Flexmojos 7.1.0-SNAPSHOT a try ... this should not be having this dependency anymore.

Comment: are you sure this dependency exist (maven could not doanload it automatically in known repository ) !

Answer (score 1):

Flexmojos-maven-plugin version 7.0.x is built using FDK 4.12.1.20140427. This FDK declared as dependency to this maven plugin.
You need firstly mavenize FDK 4.12.1.20140427 and put it to you maven repository. Only after that you can mavenize other versions of FDK.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty work around is to change flexmojo-parent pom file : and edit by hand :

```
<flex.version>4.13.0.20140701</flex.version>
```

until flexmojo developpers comes with a better response .

Comment: Ahem ... I'm the flexmojos developer and as I already posted ... Flexmojos 7.1.0-SNAPSHOT should no longer have any dependency on any flex sdk resources (But it won't work if you don't give it any version). If it still does, give me a note an I'll re-re-check that.

Comment: ok , thanks for you reply . is your last version published in maven repos ?

Comment: It's currently published in the Sonatype Snapshot repo at: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ and will be released as soon as I have finished support for the apache Falcon compiler and FlexJS.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply and for your work on flex projects :)

Comment: @ChristoferDutz trying to compile , got this error : [ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin net.flexmojos.oss:flexmojos-maven-plugin:7.1.0-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact net.flexmojos.oss:flexmojos-maven-plugin:jar:7.1.0-SNAPSHOT in flex-mojos-plugin-repository (http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup) -> [Help 2] any ideas

Comment: Ive been trying this repo http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/sonatype-snapshots , the snapshot is there fine . but some dependencies are missing ( net.flexmojos.oss:flexmojos-generator-api:jar:7.1.0-SNAPSHOT) . recently i struggled a lot building flex apps with flex mojo and apache SDK We appreciate if you make some king of post in wich you explain how to build and some complete pom examples . THANKS .

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The problem is that flexmojos relys on the core plugin to build other parts of itself. So you need to build flexmojos with the "minimal" profile once and from then on you're good to go with the normal build. But be warned: To build Flexmojos with all tests you currently need about 6 different versions of the Flex SDK ;-) ... but if you don't want to run the testsuite ... 4.13 should be enough :-)

Comment: @ChristoferDutz, is there an ETA for FM 7.1.0 yet?  Trying to use the SNAPSHOT is a huge PITA for, example, reproducible builds on a multi-server Jenkins build farm. Unfortunately I've had little luck trying to use 7.1.0-SNAPSHOT effectively.

Comment: Currently I'm sort of working on Apache Flex FlexPMD so my time for Flexmojos is limited. I had started working on FlexJS support, but eventually I'll stash that and do a release of 7.1 and add FlexJS support to 7.2

Answer (score 0):

I have written quite a bit of documentation lately, please check-out at: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/Preparing+FDKs+for+Maven+builds

The short version: 
We have created a maven extension that should automatically download and install Flex SDKs as they are referenced in the maven build. Also Flexmojos 7.1.0-SNAPSHOT has been updated to no longer contain a reference to any FDK artifact. Also we now use 3-segment versions such as: 4.14.1